# Memory usage maxed out on Windows 10 with Task Manager's processes only showing a few GB used

Tags: memory, docker-for-windows

I have been noticing when my computer sits overnight idle, after a day or few it gets increasingly slower. I once left it on for 5 days without using it, and when I came back it was completely unusable and I could barely move the mouse.

Now I'm noticing that it is because the memory is being maxed out. After force closing the background Docker running, the memory usage returned to normal, so Docker seems to be continuously taking up more memory over time. Any idea what is going on here, or do I just need to force close all Docker processes whenever I'm not using it?

I only have a single Docker container, and the container what not running at the time I took these screenshots:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: I find that task manager is not the correct tool.  Try the SYSINT range such as process explorer.  In fact I have replaced task manager with this, on my machines.

Comment: You probably have a driver leaking memory. It’s helpful to us to provide screenshots of your system NOT running memory intensive programs.